# Is multiple calls of AddRazorPages allowed?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0, servicecollection

In Program.cs I'm calling to AddRazorPages to setup Fluent Validation and some localization stuff. Unfortunately this has a lot of repetive code and I'm wondering if it is perfectly legal to reduce it by calling AddRazorPages twice?

I have tried to run the code and it seems to work, but can any one confirm the new version is effectively the same as the old version?

#### Current Program.cs

```
if (isDevelopment)
    // Run-time compilation added during development
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention()))
        .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>();
            fv.LocalizationEnabled = true;
            fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = false;
        })
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
else
    // No Run-time compilation needed when deployed
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention()))
        .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>();
            fv.LocalizationEnabled = true;
            fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = false;
        })
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

#### New Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention()))
    .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
    {
        fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>();
        fv.LocalizationEnabled = true;
        fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = false;
    })
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

// Run-time compilation added during development
if (isDevelopment)
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: have you tried the code yet? though, i doubt it works as you hoped for. the thing is, `AddRazorPages()` and `AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions...)` may create different stuff altogether. you should assign the first `AddRazorPages` (the one with long parameters) into a `var` then within the `if`, and call `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` on that variable.

Comment: Reading the answer of Mike Brind made me investigate this further. Looking at the source code I see no reason for the order to have any effect as ``AddRazorPages()`` does not reference ``builder.services.Configure`` whereas ``AddRazorPages(options)`` does.

but thx for the comment, it was great to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `AddRazorPages` as many times as you like. Internally, it uses a series of `TryAdd*` calls to add the various services that the method is responsible for registering. If the service is already registered with the service container, nothing happens.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/207f2c39ee1eccbc339450570fe6297026ea549c/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/DependencyInjection/MvcRazorPagesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L95